# SQL PL/SQL ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I am getting an error in the `insert` statement in Oracle PROCEDURE using CURSOR.

The entire code works but I am getting an error the Insert Statement. Where I am trying to select the `NEXTVAL` from dual for every time it loops.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AUTO AS 
BEGIN

DEClARE
    request_seq number;
    V_ID_NO schema.table_name.ID_NO%type;
    v_accno schema.table_name.accno%type;
    v_USER_NAME schema.table_name.USER_NAME%type;

    CURSOR c1 IS    
        SELECT ID_NO,accno,USER_NAME from table_name
        where DEV_TYPE = 'CUSTOMER'
    BEGIN   
        OPEN c1;
        LOOP
            FETCH c1 INTO V_ID_NO,v_accno,v_USER_NAME;  
            EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE(REQUEST_ID,POINT_ID,ACCNO,FAQ_ID,REQ_TIMESTAMP,ID_NO,TYPE,REST_TIMESTAMP,REV_NO,MSG_ID,DIST,REQUEST_TYPE,CLIENT_ID) VALUES((select arequest_seq.nextval from dual),v_accno,v_accno,v_USER_NAME,sysdate,null,null,null,null,null,null,'PEP','NONE');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(V_ID_NO)  ||'--- '|| v_accno  ||' --- '|| v_USER_NAME);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c1;
  END;
END;
```

Comment: No need for a select, simply use `arequest_seq.nextval` instead of `(select arequest_seq.nextval from dual)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are Awesome Person man...Thank you so so much. It worked!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is it possible to store that into a variable before the insert statement and use that variable to insert into multiple tables?

Comment: `var := arequest_seq.nextval;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create or replace procedure auto
as 
begin   
    for r in (
        select id_no, accno, user_name
        from   table_name
        where  dev_type = 'CUSTOMER'
    )
    loop
        insert into temp_table
             ( request_id
             , point_id
             , accno
             , faq_id
             , req_timestamp
             , id_no, type, rest_timestamp, rev_no, msg_id, dist
             , request_type
             , client_id )
        values
             ( arequest_seq.nextval
             , r.accno
             , r.accno
             , r.user_name
             , sysdate
             , null, null, null, null, null, null
             , 'PEP'
             , 'NONE' )
        returning request_id into r.id_no;

        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(r.id_no) ||' --- '|| r.accno ||' --- '|| r.user_name);
    end loop;
end;
```

Note that `arequest_seq.nextval` is used directly within the `insert` statement and captured into a variable using `rturning into`. Alternatively, you could assign it before the `insert`, as

```
r.id_no := arequest_seq.nextval;
```

Using the cursor loop record like this avoids the risk of variables retaining their values from one loop iteration to the next (although they wouldn't in your example) and also means you don't have to declare them at the top.

If it did need to declare a variable, it would go between `as` and `begin` - you don't need to nest another whole `declare-begin-end` sub-block.

In Oracle 12c, you might consider using an identity column, e.g:

```
create table temp_table
( request_id integer generated always as identity
```

Then the sequence is implicit and you can skip it in `insert` statements (you can still capture it with `returning into`).